# Finding whether the element exists in whole html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check whether an element exists in the whole page or not. Is there any way to know if the element exists in the page through jQuery?

For example:

```
<html>
     <body>
        <p id="para1" class="para_class"></p>
     </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, I have to check whether `<p>` of id *para1* exists in the DOM or not. In any case if with the help of the 'class' attribute we can know if the element exists, it also would be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For element IDs:

```
if($('#para1').length){
  //element with id exists
}
```

For element class:

```
if($('.para_class').length){
  //element with class exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

recently I faced the same problem & this is good for me.

```
if ( $('#para1').length == 1 ){ // if the id exists its length will be 1 

      alert('This Id exists');

} elseif ( $('#para1').length == 0 ){ // if the id doesn't exists its length will be 0

      alert('This Id does not exists');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late, but, to check if an input doesn't exist with an id using JQuery, you can do this:

```
if (!$('#inputid').length > 0)) {
}
```