# isset in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding whether the element exists in whole html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227087/finding-whether-the-element-exists-in-whole-html-page)

i would like make somethings:

**HTML**:

```
<span id="one">one</span>
<span id="two">two</span>
<span id="three">three</span>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
if (isset($("#one"))){
   alert('yes');
}

if (isset($("#two"))){
   alert('yes');
}

if (isset($("#three"))){
   alert('yes');
}

if (!isset($("#four"))){
   alert('no');
}
```

LIVE:

http://jsfiddle.net/8KYxe/

how can I make that?

Comment: What should be set to these spans?

Comment: What is `isset` meant to mean? The `span` has some content? It exists?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if (($("#one").length > 0)){
   alert('yes');
}

if (($("#two").length > 0)){
   alert('yes');
}

if (($("#three").length > 0)){
   alert('yes');
}

if (($("#four")).length == 0){
   alert('no');
}
```

This is what you need :)

Comment: If id is not found it will throw error

Comment: `if (!! $('#one')) { alert('yes'); }` - and so on.This is !! double not operator in JS.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `length`:

```
if($("#one").length) { // 0 == false; >0 == true
    alert('yes');
}
```

Comment: No need to have the > 0 there as 0 is evaluated as false anyway.

Comment: This indicates whether the elemnt with such ID exists. However if you want to find out if value exists for this element, you may do `if ($("#one").val()) {...}`

Comment: @Richard: Right, but `> 0` is more expressive and therefore easier to read. It might not be immediately clear to everyone that `0` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Janis - `val` will only work if they are elements with a `value` property (e.g. `input`). It can't be used to check whether or not an element has content.

Comment: @Richard: Also, with `> 0` the return type of the expression is Boolean.

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs: And OP is obviously using `SPAN` elements. SO there is no value provided. Most likely they're looking for existing elements even though the question **is very vague**.

Comment: @James should .html() be used then?

Comment: @Tomalak: `if` condition is always evaluated to Boolean in the end, even though if you provide numbers, strings or anything else.

Comment: @Janis - Yes, you could use `html` to test for contents, or `text` to test for text (ignoring child elements).

Comment: @Robert: That's true. In this case there will be not much difference, in my opinion it's cleaner nevertheless.

Comment: Something like `if ($("#one").text().length)` would work for content

Comment: @FelixKling True, but if anything you hope it would encourage people to learn what it is doing. (Not likely though, lol)

Answer (score 8):

```
function isset(element) {
    return element.length > 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8KYxe/1/

---

Or, as a jQuery extension:

```
$.fn.exists = function() { return this.length > 0; };

// later ...
if ( $("#id").exists() ) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

php.js ( http://www.phpjs.org/ ) has a `isset()` function: http://phpjs.org/functions/isset:454

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use this:

```
if ($("#one")){
   alert('yes');
}

if ($("#two")){
   alert('yes');
}

if ($("#three")){
   alert('yes');
}

if ($("#four")){
   alert('no');
}
```

Sorry, my mistake, it does not work.

Comment: `$()`always returns a jQuery object, which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Won't work, jQuery always returns jQuery object.

Comment: @FelixKling: You better copy this comment... Maybe there'll be a third person answering this way... ;)

Comment: This won't work, as jQuery will return object which evaluates to true always, it's just that the collcetion is empty (with length 0).

Comment: @RobertKoritnik And he will delete the answer then :p

Comment: Try it in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eqpqR/ jQuery return Object when div with current id is exist.

Comment: And why is that? Because `$("#four")` returns an object that evaluates to true. Change `no` to `yes` and it will alert `yes`. You made the wrong conclusion. You use the *same* condition to test whether `#three` exists. What is the logic behind that? It is not important what is  *inside* the statement, but what the *condition* is. See http://jsfiddle.net/eqpqR/1/

Answer (score -3):

```
function el(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

if (el('one') || el('two') || el('three')) { 
  alert('yes');

} else if (el('four')) {
  alert('no');
}
```