# Check if an ID exists or not using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding whether the element exists in whole html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227087/finding-whether-the-element-exists-in-whole-html-page)

Is there any way to check for if a ID $('#ID') exists in jQuery

Ex:

`$('#cart').append('<li id="456">My Product</li>');`

After running append() to something like this I want to check if my ID $('#456') exists or not. If it exits I want to change the text, else I want to append a new

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#RAM,#HDD').change(function() {

            var product = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("product");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#cart').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        $('#cart').append('<li id="'+product+'">'+ value['price'] +'</li>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Of course it will exist after you appended it (as long as `#cart` exist), there is no need to test it. What is the actual problem your are trying to solve?

Comment: Try:

`if ($('#456').length) {
 // ...
} else { 
 // ...
}`

Comment: I want to change < li > text if it exists, else I want to create a new < li >. Ive tried this, but it is not working after jquery append...

if (document.getElementById(name)) {
  // it exists
} else {
  // its not exists
}

Comment: No its not. Im asking about after append something using ajax.

Comment: @stackminu: That does not make a difference. The test for existence is always the same. Maybe if you described your problem better (as I already noted in my first comment) we would be able to help you better.

Comment: You are using one single string of numbers as an ID for possibly many elements generated in a loop, it's seems like just bad practice to me?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
if ($('#456').length)
{
 /* it exists */
}
else
{
 /* it doesn't exist */
}
```

Comment: its not working after append that div or li using ajax..!!!

Comment: *"jQuery caches the DOM"* What is that supposed to mean? It does not cache the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You can do  this to see if the selector does exist or not:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

if ($(selector).exists()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: its not working after append that div or li using ajax..!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkExists(sel) {
    var status = false;
    if ($(sel).length) status = true;
    return status;
}
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/UX78y/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Erm, I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but in order to do so you will need to rearrange your code slightly.

```
success: function(data) {
    var cart = $('#cart');
    cart.empty();
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        cart.append('<li id="'+product+'">'+ value['price'] +'</li>');
    });
    if(cart.find('#456').length) {
        cart.find('#456').text('Whatever you would like');
    }
}
```

I 'cached' your cart selector to save on DOM lookups.

Comment: It's a valid ID in HTML5 and `$('<li id="456">My product</li>').length` will *always* return `1`... the test seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: Quite. But that's the question asked, so that's the answer.

Comment: Actually i want to check its exists or not, after few scripts run. not while it appends.

Comment: Can you post some more of your code?

Comment: anyone know how to solve this ???